# Phonegap 2.0.0 - getApplicationContext

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to get Application Context inside my plugin but it throws this error:

> Can't create handler inside thread that has not called
>   Looper.prepare()

Here is my code:

```
ResourceManager manager = ResourceManager.getInstance(this, this.ctx.getApplicationContext());
```

I even changed my code to :

```
ResourceManager manager = ResourceManager.getInstance(this, this.cordova.getContext());
```

and

```
ResourceManager manager = ResourceManager.getInstance(this, this.cordova.getActivity());
```

also tried:

```
ResourceManager manager = ResourceManager.getInstance(this, cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

but it still throws the same error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED: The issue was not related to getting applicationContext, there was a problem in the ResourceManager